# Yahoo oauth and apis implementation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I mostly worked on Socila apis. Currently I am working on Yahoo apis. I need to fetch contacts and profile information from Yahoo using APIs. I studied their documentation but don't get what to do. I need to implement using JavaScript. Can anyone suggest me sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use YQL. 
Example of how to get the profile information:
[link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20=%20me)